# Cocos2d with transparent background

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to create a 'game' using Cocos2d that will play over the users home, or current screen?

I was thinking that a snapshot of the current screen would be enough, but the screen has already switched before i could grab the users screen when the game starts.

Basically, i want the game to appear as it is riding on top of the users screen, with the current icon setup and groupings in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Apps can not grab the screen contents of the user's phone, only what they themselves draw to the screen. Apps are sandboxed so they have no programmatic access to anything they don't own or the user didn't allow the app to access.

One reason for that is privacy. A random app shouldn't be allowed to "see" what apps the user has installed or whatever picture is his/her wallpaper phone.

Comment: Thank you  - I was not sure.